# Get Mousepointer state in C#

Tags: c#, windows

I am attempting some interop with another application.  It would be helpful to be able to detect when the mouse is an hourglass and when it returns to a pointer again.  Is there a way to detect this?

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, there isn't a way.
You can only change the icon of the cursor, not get the current icon. `User32.dll` has a GetCursorInfo function, but that only returns the position of the global cursor, and some flags about it (whether it's hidden, why it's hidden). It doesn't return a handle to the current icon.
It does return the handle, and you can check if it's equal to the handle of the WAIT cursor - however, the app could be using a custom cursor. There's no reliable way to tell the pixels of the cursor.